# Inverted Deadman Switch (Basic theory, but lost for component ideas.)

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

Rather than...
Intial state current OFF;
Foot pressure = current ON.

Looking for...
Intial state current ON;
Foot pressure = current OFF.

Looking for ideas on components to modify a foot pedal I already have.
Don't worry this won't be used on machinery, it has a extremely niche purpose I want to test out.

Comment: Buy a foot pedal with an normally-closed switch.

Comment: It is for something that is extremely low voltage, likely less than a digital watch. Would be uneconomical to go buy another pedal when I can just modify this old one for few cents.

Comment: Another note, all the normally-closed pedals for sale are 2 step deactivate/activate. I need something that is 1 step functioning.

Comment: can you post a photo of the inside of the switch.

Comment: Maybe the question could be salvaged if you tell us what you are switching on and off. You don't have to divulge proprietary details. But what is the power source? What is the range of voltage the solution needs to operate over? How much current does the load consume?

Comment: Thanks for the interest mkeith: 1-2 Volts max; 24 AWG possibly thinner. Current maybe .6ish

Comment: Look inside the foot pedal. If it uses a standard microswitch, which is usually a changeover device, there may well be a NC (Normally Closed) contact sitting there unused. If not, look for ways to fit a microswitch in there. (They come with a huge variety of levers, paddles and rollers to operate them). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miniature_snap-action_switch

Comment: Thanks Brian that turned out to be the perfect option. I happen to have a micro switch left over from something I dismantled.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a small relay with a battery/power supply to operate via the foot switch and invert the signal using the normally closed contacts.